# Flattening tuple with repeating key?

Tags: python, tuples

I’m trying to turn

`x = [((1, ‘code’, ‘XXXX’), (1, ‘ref’, ‘112B’))]`

into `[(1, (‘code’, ‘XXXX’), (‘ref’, ‘112B’))]`

Basically the first number is the key.

I tried using `itertools.groupby` function but it became a mess on my end.

Comment: how did you use itertools.groupby, can you show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first convert the list into a temporary dictionary using [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and then convert it into the format you want.

```
from collections import defaultdict

x = [((1, 'code', 'XXXX'), (1, 'ref', '112B'))]
temp = defaultdict(list)

for t in x[0]:
    temp[t[0]].append(t[1:])

print(temp)
# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {1: [('code', 'XXXX'), ('ref', '112B')]})

final = [(k, *v) for k, v in temp.items()]
print(final)
# [(1, ('code', 'XXXX'), ('ref', '112B'))]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), then you can try this solution. It first flattens the list of nested tuples to a list of tuples using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), then applies `groupby()` to group by the first item in each tuple. The groupby `key` is accessed with [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter). Other option is to use `key=lambda x: x[0]`.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain
from operator import itemgetter

x = [((1, "code", "XXXX"), (1, "ref", "112B"))]

groups = [
    (k, *tuple(x[1:] for x in g))
    for k, g in groupby(chain.from_iterable(x), key=itemgetter(0))
]

print(groups)
```

Output:

```
[(1, ('code', 'XXXX'), ('ref', '112B'))]
```

**Note:** This assumes your initial tuples are sorted. If they are not you can apply [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
groups = [
    (k, *tuple(x[1:] for x in g))
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(chain.from_iterable(x)), key=itemgetter(0))
]
```